# How to test auto-renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an app with an auto-renwable item in the inApp-Purchase.
Let's say, with an period of 7 days.

If a test-User buys the item...
How can I check the expiration-date?
I can observe it with restoreCompletedTransaction, but there will be an Dialog to the user. Which is not so nice. Is there any other way without a server?

How can I handle the test-phase?
I don't see a way to shorten the 7 days... does it mean I have to wait 7 days, to see that I'm handling it right if the user doesn't subscribe again?

thank you
xnz

Comment: For testing, the duration of auto-renewable subscriptions in the sandbox have been shortened to just a few minutes. Also, the products will only renew a limited number of times in the sandbox. (like 5 times) These 2 facts make it seem like renewing works inconsistently in the sandbox.  But since iTunes will only send you the *latest* auto-renewed receipt when you verify, you may not realize that there were a number of receipts between your original and the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the receipt to a server of yours and have it check and re check the receipt. When the subscription is prolonged your server receives an additional receipt indicating that.

I am not sure if this is possible within the app. You need a certificate and a shared-secret to verify auto renewables. It might be a bad idea to have the certificate and the shared-secret within your app.

You can find Apples documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

Comment: You *can* do the verification from within the app, but it is discouraged because, as Dirk states, you'll be including your secret in every version of the app.

Comment: @Dirk Can you help me with creating the product-id for Subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some info by Apple that recommends to verify the receipt on your own server for security reasons:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/index.html

They also say, to know the status of your IAP (in the article, Consumable, but I guess it would work for subscriptions too) you can save the receipt, recall it when needed and verify it again, receiving an updated receipt.